# Ansible Inventory

Tags: ansible

Can anyone help me in inventory variable in Ansible?

I have a server where root login via ssh is not permitted and I used to login on server with a normal user (MYUSER) and then `su -` to become root. 
I have ssh key-based authentication with user (MYUSER). 
Now, I want to execute something like below.

```
ansible --private-key /PATH/TO/PRIVATE/KEY.KEY -i INVENTORY -m shell -a "whoami" all
```

But I am getting output as MYUSER.

I want to login on server with my ssh keys in user MYUSER and, then execute some commands using shell module on server via root user
:NOTE: I have root password to provide in inventory. 
Below is the inventory that I created. (^ ^) I know it is wrong.

```
test-web.example.com ansible_ssh_host=X.X.X.X ansible_ssh_user=MYUSER ansible_become_method=su ansible_become_user=root ansible_become_pass=Xjdt@mdaj12
```

Execution:

```
[root@server ansi]# ansible --private-key /root/MASTER/audit/key.key -i test -m shell -a "whoami" all
test-web.example.com | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
MYUSER
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible will not become a privileged user until you explicitly ask to.

There is `-b` switch in ansible CLIs for that. Try:

```
ansible all -b --private-key /root/MASTER/audit/key.key -i test -m shell -a "whoami"
```

Comment: Ok thanks.... I will try...
So what I did in my host file.... is it correct or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Like Konstanting said the -b or --become switch is correct.

in playbooks you can also add in every task or globally

```
become: yes
```

and optionally additionally if you don't want to become root

```
become: yes
become_user: user2
```

Your hostfile line looks ok

however i guess if you don't need to specify ansible_become_method=su (i think ansible will either use sudo or su by default only if you want it to force using su you need to specify it)

and also not ansible_ssh_host if the inventory name is a valid domain that is bound to the IP:
test-web.example.com

also you probably dont need to specify:

```
ansible_become_user=root
```

only if you don't want the default become behaviour to be switching to the default root but to another manually created user from yourself.

therefore my lines look a bit shorter, more like this if the hostname is a real domain address!:

> www.domain.com ansible_user=nonrootuser ansible_become_pass=ROOTPASSWD

btw: ansible_user is the same as ansible_ssh_user just shorter ;) the same